# SQL Error: 'Fatal Error'

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to output some minutes 7 days after a meeting has taken place. I have inserted in the following code only to get a fatal error message.

```
 <?php
$id = $_GET['meeting_id'];
$from = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $row['date_update'] . '-7 days' ) ); 

$result = $this->db->get ('SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Minutes ON Minutes.meeting_id = Meetings.meeting_id WHERE Rooms.date >= "' . $from . '" AND Rooms.date <= NOW() AND Minutes.meeting_id = $id')

or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo '<h3>There Arent Any Minutes For This Meeting Yet</h3>';
    } else {

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Title: '. $info['title']." </td>";
        echo "<td><br/><br/>" .'Subject: '. $info['subject']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/><br/>" .'Next Subject: '. $info['next_subject']."</td>";

        echo '<br/><br/><a href="attendees.php?meeting_id=' . $info['meeting_id'] . '" target="_blank">Attendees</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="apologies.php?meeting_id=' . $info['meeting_id'] . '" target="_blank">Apologies</a>';

        }
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

the error message i am getting is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in E:\webareas\hj942\CW\meetings\conference\viewminutes.php on line 59
```

line 59 is the query at $result.

anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$this" is used inside a Class to refer to itself. As you're not inside a class, the php script produces an error. Use mysql_query() instead, and of course you'll need to connect to your DB first

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$this->db` on the 5th line of your code and it's not a object context. You probably want to use `$db`, but also you need to initiate db connection on `$db` variable for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First, establish a MySQL connection:

```
$db = mysql_connect('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_password');
```

Then, use `$db` variable with the `mysql_query()` function instead of `$this->db->get`:

```
$result = mysql_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Minutes ON Minutes.meeting_id = Meetings.meeting_id WHERE Rooms.date >= "' . $from . '" AND Rooms.date <= NOW() AND Minutes.meeting_id = $id')
```

Or even without the `$db` variable (if you use only one database):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Meetings INNER JOIN Minutes ON Minutes.meeting_id = Meetings.meeting_id WHERE Rooms.date >= "' . $from . '" AND Rooms.date <= NOW() AND Minutes.meeting_id = $id')
```